# Keeping the original file name when batch processing GDAL translate?

Tags: qgis, gdal, convert, qgis-processing, geotiff-tiff

I would like to convert .tif files to Idrisi or ENVI format. I would like to do a batch process, keeping the original filename. When I choose: "run as a batch process", as I can see, I still have to set the output name and directory for each file?

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the output to take the file name as **an additional string** which will appear in front of a string specified by you. So what you could do is in the first row, click the ellipses button (shown in red circle), define a path (e.g. to an empty folder) and use a single character like an underscore (shown in green circle). Then click *Save*.

[image: Translate output]

You will receive another pop up menu for **Autofill settings**.

Select the following options:

- Autofill mode - `Fill with parameter values`
- Parameter to use - `Input layer`

[image: Autofill settings]

Then click *OK*. I would also suggest setting the **Load in QGIS** parameter to `No` for all your layers. Then run your process.

When it is finished, open the **Python Console** from the menubar `Plugins > Python Console` and run the following code to remove the underscore from the output files, leaving you with the original file name using [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename):

```
import os
os.chdir("path/to/folder/")
for fileName in os.listdir("."):
    os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("_", ""))
```

Comment: @dtanon - Most welcome, hope it was helpful :)